# Editing selected text in a text area on right click with chrome ext

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm very new to chrome extensions and I want to create a very simple extension that changes all the bullet points in a piece of text to asterisk(*).

This only needs to work on one page and fill in one textarea element.

The user submits a piece for our website through a form and a member of our team approves all these vacancies. In this approval process they have to go through and manually change every bullet point to an asterisk. Ideally they will just have to highlight the whole text, right click and select the extension to replace all the bullet points.

I have made an extension using one of the sample extensions from google. It does everything i want apart from replacing all the text in the textArea with the edited text.

I've tried calling the function onLoad, finding the element the click was registered in and a bunch of other stuff but i can't seem to get it to work.

manifest.json

```
  "name": "Replacing bullet points",
  "description": "put a desciption here",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

sample.js

```
// Copyright (c) 2010 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

function replaceOnClick(info, tab) {
  var uneditedText = info.selectionText;
  var detailsField = document.getElementById("element ID which definitely exists");

  console.log("highlighted text: " + uneditedText);
  var bulletPointsReplaced = uneditedText.replace(/[\u2022\u2023\u25E6\u2043\u2219]/g, "*");
  console.log("all done: " + bulletPointsReplaced);

  detailsField.value = bulletPointsReplaced; // doesn't work as ID returns null
}


var context = "selection";
var title = "Test '" + context + "' menu item";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],"onclick": replaceOnClick});
```

Any help would be massively appreciated! I'm sure it's a simple fix but i can't make sense of it for the life of me.

Edit: Essentially, i just want to know how to find the ID of the element i selected the text in and then replace the text in the element

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden and empty background page, not related to the web page. You need an additional content script to be able to modify the web page. In this case it would make sense to run it using chrome.tabs.executeScript. See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: thank you @wOxxOm ! I've changed the name of sample.js to content.js and updated the manifest. I tried using `"onclick": chrome.tabs.executeScript` on the final line of the content.js file but it stopped showing the right click option at all. I understand what you're saying in that the script doesn't know which page it should be looking at when looking for an element but I'm just not sure where in my code to put what you mentioned. A small pointer in the right direction would be fab! I've looked through the doc but i can't work out how to relate it to my code at all :(